# A list of item or items?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it grammatically okay to use a singular noun after "a list of"?
For example, which one is correct among the following sentences?

- I have a list of item.
- I have a list of items.

I thought the noun must be plural. Am I correct?

Comment: Please consider waiting at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, as suggested in [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: @Ben Kovitz I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list implies more than one. So normally it would be

> a list of [plural noun]

A singular noun is possible to create a humorous or emphatic effect as in

> My recommended list of useful words for a manager is a list of one, namely the word "No."